# ASP.Net/Powerhell: Command like Update-Database to run execute method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, powershell

I'm looking for advice for the following scenario.

I have a ASP.MVC/Entity framework project.

As a part of the app I have a data structure defined in code and when changed I need to sync with my database(s).

To sync I've written a SyncWithDatabase() method.

To execute this method I can setup some controller to run it. But that feels lame.

I like the way EF migrations works where I can run Update-Database with -ConnectionStringName  and update any database I need.

So one solution I thought would be to create an empty migration and put SyncWithDatabase() in it?

Dream solution would be if there's way a way to execute commands directly in the Package Manager Console like this:

Execute "Foo.Bar.SyncWithDatabase()" -ConnectionStringName = "FooConnectionstring"

Similar to Update-Database only no need to create a migration.

Can this be done?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use code first as it was intended?

Comment: Can you put `SyncWithDatabase()` in the `Seed` method?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://jeffmurr.com/blog/?p=142) ?

Comment: @JamieDunstan this will probably be my solution for this case, but I'm still interested the requested solution. Quite powerful to be able to access method of an webapp seamless using commandline with actual db access.